# Using autorun to automatically open vbscript

Tags: autorun

I want autorun.inf to change my USB icon and automatic open VBScript.

Here is my first autorun (this one works fine)

```
[autorun]
Label=Faisal
icon=System32.ico
```

Here is my second autorun

```
[autorun]
ShellExecute = README.vbs
```

For some reason the second autorun will not work. Please can you explain to me what i have done wrong and how i merge the two scripts together.

Comment: You have already [asked this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1360690/can-i-run-two-autoruns-in-the-same-folder) and you have not responded to my last comment. Please don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

```
[AutoRun]
shellexecute="Readme.txt"
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/autorun-cmds#shellexecute